# Does schedule task affected on restarting windows service?

Tags: windows

Windows service is created for sending reports to concern person every friday. The DLL and app.config file is posted on server. The DLL which is created by windows service is located on the server in Bin folder and app.config file also located outside Bin folder on the server. Now, I have modified app.config file by adding my email id in BCC locally and pasted modified one into the server. Now, friday has gone but i didnt get any mail. Do i require to restart Windows service for modified app.config file? If i restart windows service does schedule task affected and send a mail before next friday comes? What should i do to get app.config changes reflected on the server without schedule task get affect. 
Please give me some idea to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your service will almost surely require a restart to pick up your new app.config changes.

Have you created a Scheduled Task as well? That seems redundant if you already have a service. Please clarify.